# Why interface only for Bean loading in Spring Application Context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was trying to load a class in application context which implements an interface, I encountered two situations

1. When interface **GenericDao** don't have any declared method:
   Here in this case my class CriteriaQuerySampleDao loads as per below code in application context there is no issue

```
CriteriaQuerySampleDao dao= context.getBean(CriteriaQuerySampleDao.class);
```

2. When my interface **GenericDao** do have declared method and which is implemented by my class **CriteriaQuerySampleDao** :

   Here in this case my class don't get loaded in application context of spring as per below code

```
CriteriaQuerySampleDao dao= context.getBean(CriteriaQuerySampleDao.class);
```

and throws

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.journaldev.spring.config.CriteriaQuerySampleDao' available
```

but when I load it by below code which is using interface GenericDao of my class CriteriaQuerySampleDao  it loads successfully asper below code

```
GenericDao dao= context.getBean(GenericDao.class);
```

can some one explain why I am forced to load **CriteriaQuerySampleDao** class by **GenericDao** interface if my class is implementing aeven a single method of interface.

I am not sure about details, is it custom in spring?

**GenericDao Interface**

```
interface GenericDao<T>
{

    Session getSession();

    Class<T> getDefaultMappedObject();
}
```

**CriteriaQuerySampleDao** Class implementing GenericDao

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class CriteriaQuerySampleDao implements GenericDao<MyDBTable>
{
    protected final static Logger logger= LogManager.getLogger(CriteriaQuerySampleDao.class);
    
    @Inject
    SessionFactory                sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public Session getSession()
    {
        Session session= null;
        try
        {
            logger.debug(" ++++ getSession try ++++ ");
            session= sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            logger.debug(" ++++ getSession catch ++++ ", ex);
            session= sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
        return session;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Class<MyDBTable> getDefaultMappedObject()
    { return MyDBTable.class; }
    
}
```

**LocalHibernateConfig** Class  Configuration And Class Having Main Method:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value= {"classpath:hibernate.properties"}, ignoreResourceNotFound= true)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan
@Component(value= "LocalHibernateConfig")
public class LocalHibernateConfig
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context= new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        // context.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("local");
        context.register(LocalHibernateConfig.class);
        context.refresh();
        
        LocalHibernateConfig lch= context.getBean(LocalHibernateConfig.class);
        logger.debug(" ++++ Properties is null "+(lch.properties==null)+" properties: "+lch.getProperties());
        
        CriteriaQuerySampleDao dao= context.getBean(CriteriaQuerySampleDao.class);
        // GenericDao dao= context.getBean(GenericDao.class);
        logger.debug(" ++++ dao: "+(dao==null));
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your code is dangerous and can (and will) leak sessions and thus connections, leading to an unresponsive application. Never use `openSession` if `getCurrentSession` fails let it fail.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you have a code coverage tool, like jacoco, attached to the JVM when building.  It creates a Proxy class to handle the coverage, and that Proxy class implements your interface, so while its an instance of your interface, its not actually an instance of your Impl.

Comment: This has nothing to do with code coverage tools but it has with proxies. Spirng by default generates interface based proxies and hence you have an object in the context which is the interface but not actual the implementation as that resides inside the proxy. If you define interfaces you should also use them for programming instead of concrete classes. If you don't ditch the interfaces as they don't add anything apparently.

Comment: That still is an interface based proxy which now extends/implements 2 interfaces.

Comment: @M. Deinum so this is proxy, but why this is happening I need to know means how internally its working, that if my interface have single method then i can't load object of my class by class itself in context, while same I can when my interface don't any method declaration, how this is enforcing and working? if you have good reference please provide soi can learn it.

Comment: The spring reference guide. The `@Transactional` is applied with AOP. By default AOP is implemented using proxies, the default proxy mechanism is to use in terface based proxies. If there are no methods in your implementation/interface there is nothing to proxy and a proxy isn't created.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for making me understand now I got what to search I just needed initial thread, thx alot.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to the way proxy interfaces are generated for enabling transaction support. You can change the behavior by setting the `proxyTargetClass` attribute of the `@EnableTransactionManagement` to `true`:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass= true)
@ComponentScan
@Component(value= "LocalHibernateConfig")
public class LocalHibernateConfig {

}
```

Also see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html#proxyTargetClass--

The reason behind this is that `@EnableTransactionManagement` is implemented using the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) with dynamically generated decorator classes.

Spring can create the dynamic decorator in two ways, [default java proxies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) or CGLib. Default java proxies can only be generated for classes that implement an interface. In the case of `CriteriaQuerySampleDao` it implements an interface so Spring will resort to a default java proxy.

Comment: M not sure about your solution, My focus is for CriteriaQuerySampleDao  & GenericDao since if any single method GenericDao have which CriteriaQuerySampleDao   is implementing then AnnotationConfigApplicationContext  is not able to load and instantiate whne I provide CriteriaQuerySampleDao.class to getBean() method , but same is instantiated when I provide GenericDao.class, now I am able to instantiate CriteriaQuerySampleDao object via context by passing CriteriaQuerySampleDao.class to getBean() only when my interface don't have any method, why this way spring is behaving this is my main doubt

Comment: This was one point another point is , wht  we call it means how we define this working and all details about it, can provide me some links for references.

Comment: Hi @sihaya thanks for reply I tried (proxyTargetClass= true) and and it worked but as I requested,my point was to understand how this is happening and what this process and phenomenon of Spring working is called can share me good references to understand it